# Symfony2: Conditional bundle configuration sections with required fields

Tags: symfony, configuration

Just like in the title. I would like to have section in my bundle configuration that is once enabled - it would have some required fields. Currently I don't know how to achieve that. I tried canBeEnabled() and canBeDisabled() options like described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#optional-sections . But with no luck. I mean, even if section is disabled, if it contains required fields - the error will be thrown. What I would like to achieve is to have thrown error when fields are not filled ONLY if section is enabled. Is there any way to achieve that?

My config validation:

```
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('defaults')->canBeDisabled()
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('firewall')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('user')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->arrayNode('controllers')
                        ->children()
                            ->booleanNode('registration')->defaultTrue()->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
```

And in my config:

```
mybundle:
    defaults:
        user: default
        firewall: default
        controllers:
            registration: true
```

I would like to be able to disable "defaults", but if this section is enabled (what should be by default): `user` and `firewall` should be required to be explicitly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config tree works as you expect. The only change I would make is to change `canBeDisabled()` to `caBeEnabled()`. Though that is just my opinion and makes little difference. I think you may be confusing how it works.

Your configuration of:

```
mybundle:
    defaults:
        user: default
        firewall: default
        controllers:
            registration: true
```

will use the whole tree for validation. The output will contain an extra key at `$sonfig['defaults']['enabled']` set to true. As per your config tree, both `user` and `firewall` MUST contain a value.

Now, If you specify a config.yml like:

```
mybundle: ~
```

Everything within the `defaults` branch is skipped. The resulting array will look like `$sonfig['defaults']['enabled'] = false`. No default values are added to the output. Nothing. That `enabled` key is a quick method of detection.

To enable/disable a branch, you will need to restructure your config.yml in such a way that all parameters are under a single key. Something like (without knowing the purpose of the bundle it's difficult to guess a suitable name):

```
mybundle:
    access:
        defaults:
            user: default
            firewall: default
            controllers:
                registration: true
```

The the config tree will look like:

```
$rootNode
->children()
    ->arrayNode('access')
    ->canBeDisabled()
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('defaults')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('firewall')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('user')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->arrayNode('controllers')
                        ->children()
                            ->booleanNode('registration')->defaultTrue()->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();
```

Now a configuration can look like:

```
mybundle:
    access: ~
```

Or even not declared at all:

```
mybundle:
    other_non_optional_key: foo
```

On a side note, I don't like the idea of having to use an extra nesting level. I would [consider it a bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17153) within `canBeDisabled()` when required fields are present. You can accomplish something similar by replacing `isRequired()` with `defaultValue()` and using a custom `validate()` method.

Comment: Ok, but I would like to disable only one branch of configuration, so I would like something like: `mybundle: defaults: ~` . But it doesn't work, branch is still being validated for required fields.

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda Updated answer

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda Your question has been answered. Perhaps you would like to accept.